# Own data for everyuser in django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

So I am building a to do app in Django. I have created databases for the users and todo items. But I have a problem, how can each user have its own data. Like every user should add their own data. It seems like there is no answer out there. 
My models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My forms.py

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']
```

So how can I connect those both. I have red that I have to use foreign key. But I really don't understand how I can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) in the `Task` model that refers to the user that constructed it:

```
# app/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

You can then make a `ModelForm` where you *exclude* the `user`. For example:

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms
from app.models import Task

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        exclude = ['user']
```

Then in the view we can "inject" the user in the instance we create, for example:

```
# app/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from app.forms import TaskForm

@login_required
def create_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = TaskForm()
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form': form})
```

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
>   [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
>   to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
>   This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
>   browser.

Comment: Wow that was amazing. Thank you so much

Comment: What does exclude in this context mean

Comment: @LalliGarden: `exclude = ['user']`, you do not add it as a form field (so that the user can not select *another* user to own the `Task` object).